# (C++) What happens to heap objects created inside an if statement after the statement is over?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, heap-memory

as the title suggests I was wondering about the availability of the heap objects I create inside if statements/for loops/any other functions, after the closing bracket is called. As a minimalistic example:

```
class Foo
{
private:
    int Bar;
public:
    Foo(int bar) : Bar(bar) {}
    int GetBar()
    {
        return Bar;
    }
};

int main()
{
    if (true)
    {
        Foo* foo = new Foo(6);
    }
    foo.GetBar();
}
```

In this case, I'd expect the instance of foo I've created inside the scope of the if statement to survive after the closing bracket, since I created it on the heap with "new". However, I cannot access it after the closing brackets and foo.GetBar() can't be used. I've verified that when I use "new", no destructor is called on the closing bracket of the if statement (as opposed to when I just instantiate it on the stack), but I cannot get the reference anymore. Does that mean that I am simply losing reference to the object but it is still in the memory, causing a memory leak ? Is there a way to hold on to the reference after the closing brackets ?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: The pointer `foo` will go out of scope but the dynamically allocated object of type `Foo` will still exist and not be destroyed automatically. Note that you can't use poniter `foo` after the `if`. Also you need to use `->` instead of `.` with `foo`.

Answer (score 2):

The memory from `new` will not be deleted unless you manually use `delete`. But the pointer `foo` will be deleted after `if`.
To avoid memory leak, you need to always have that pointer. For example, you can

```cpp
int main()
{
    Foo* foo;
    if (true)
    {
        foo = new Foo(6);
    }
    foo->GetBar();
}
```

Thanks to fabian, who noticed that foo is a pointer that need `->` rather than `.`.

Comment: The pointer will **not** be deleted; it will be destroyed, and its destructor doesn't do anything. +1.

Comment: @fabian `.` works perfectly fine for member access for any type. Some, like raw pointers, don't have any members to access though.